# Twitter embed not working on Chrome due to same site cookie rule

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, twitter, samesite

I'm getting JavaScript errors from an embed at https://publish.twitter.com.  The embed works in Firefox, but the Twitter JavaScript widget is apparently not abiding by the Same Site Cookie rules in Chrome.  I'm getting errors such as:

"indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute" with the following cookies mentioned:

```
 | Name          | Domain & Path                              |
 |---------------|--------------------------------------------|
 | _ga           | .twitter.com/                              |
 | metrics_token | .syndication.twitter.com/i/jot/syndication |
```

Is there a way around this?
Here is the embed:

```
 <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/msdev">Tweets by Microsoft Developer</a>
 <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Can you to a specific embed that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: @rowan_m Sure, I edited the post.  Thanks